# Set the selected option according to the url (using Symfony)

Tags: jquery, symfony

I have this in my view in twig:

```
<select id="songs">
  {% for song in songs %}
    <option value={{ song.songId }}>{{ song.name }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

My route looks like this:

```
songs/{albumId}/{songId}
```

What I want is to set the selected option according to the `songId` from the route.

I tried with `$.getUrlVars()`, but honestly I don't know where to put it. Wherever I paste it, I get

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'getUrlVars'`

Can you please help me to achieve this? Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_param2') == song.songId %}
   selected
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to do this with JQuery you can use it with window.location.

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
//Assuming that the last "slashpath" is the songId
$("#songs").val(pathArray[pathArray.length-1]);
```